# Why does find_withtag not return an ID in some case?

Tags: python, tkinter, find

Can anyone explain why I get an output of :- tags applied to oval are ('paul', '20', '1993', '1.1.1.1') but tags found on oval are only  () () (1,) (1,)

Why arnt the first 2 tests returning an Id of 1 also ?

```
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()
xtra1 = "20"
yrbl = "1993"
prefix = "1.1.1.1"
c = tk.Canvas (root)

id1 = c.create_oval(10,10, 120, 120, tags=("paul",xtra1, yrbl, prefix ),fill="red", )
t1 = c.gettags(id1)

test = c.find_withtag(xtra1)
test1 = c.find_withtag(yrbl)
test2 = c.find_withtag(prefix)
test3 = c.find_withtag("paul")

print ("tags applied to oval are",t1, "but tags found on oval are only ", test,test1,test2,test3,)
c.pack()
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Ahah after 6 hours of head scratching, tags cant be integers. They must be strings. Even though I applied them as string variables, the withtags method treats them as integers and ignores them. so will have to add a string char such as a space character to store them in a tag.

Answer (score 0):

Tags cannot be integers or strings that look like integers, because they are indistinguishable from item ids.

When you do `c.find_withtag(xtra1)`, tkinter interprets that as finding an item with an id of whatever is in `xtra1` since you're passing in a string of digits.

From the tcl/tk canvas man page:

> Each item may also have any number of tags associated with it. A tag is just a string of characters, and it may take any form **except that of an integer**. For example, “x123” is OK but “123” is not.